# Получение размера изображения после его загрузки

Tags: javascript, jquery, img

Делаю предпросмотр элемента, который имеет повторяющийся фон. В зависимости от того большая или маленькая картинка фон должен меняться через background-size. Я заметил, что это работает только в тех случаях, если картинка уже загрузилась в кеш (например, со второго раза если зайти на страницу). Как сделать так, чтобы предпросмотр корректно работал даже если мы открывыем страницу впервые?

```
// вставляем изображение в src img
$('.elements[action=1] img').attr('src', file);

// получаем размер изображения        
var img_width = $('.elements[action=1] img').prop('naturalWidth');

// рассчитываем ratio для background-size
var img_width_mini = img_width * 0.5;
var img_width_big = img_width * 2;

// вставляем в бекраунд в див
 $('.fon_mini').css('background-size', img_width_mini);
 $('.fon_big').css('background-size', img_width_big);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипт отрабатывает раньше, чем загрузится картинка. Установите обработчик события загрузки

```
$('.elements[action=1] img').attr('src', file);
$('.elements[action=1] img').load(function() {
  var img_width = $(this).prop('naturalWidth');
  ...
});
```